# How to set a daily reminder at a specific time in Pacific time

Tags: python, datetime, pytz, pause

```
import datetime
import pytz
import pause
#import pause
n=0
while True:

    pause.until(datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 10, 12))
    pst_timezone = pytz.timezone("US/Pacific")
    time=datetime.datetime.now(pst_timezone).time()
    print(time)
```

I'm trying to implement this code into my twitter bot.I want it to tweet at 9am every day. The problem is that I live in California so we have daylight savings which changes based on laws. I know that pytz keeps that into account. I don't know how I might make it so that it continuously tweets at that same time since I would need to keep checking if there has been any new daylight savings changes in the laws. So I can't do something simple. I was initially going to add one day by making days a variable with months,changing then years. However that won't work because Pacific time varies.

Comment: For what it's worth, the formula for how daylight saving time in the USA is calculated hasn't changed in more than 10 years now. It's not like it changes all the time. You almost certainly won't be able to build a program in Python that will keep running for one year, let alone multiple years. A better approach would be to schedule your Python program to run using some other mechanism (e.g. `cron` on a Unix system or a Scheduled Task on Windows).

Comment: I was going to have it run in the cloud with  https://www.pythonanywhere.com/  this was supposed to be a simple project haha. I was hopping there was would be an easier way with an already built it library.